# How to circumvent SPICE limitations (500 M rows) to create a QuickSight dashboard for a big data set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-quicksight

My goal is to quickly & dynamically visualize a big data set (> 500 M rows) using QuickSight. To achieve quick query times, it's necessary to load all of the data into SPICE. However, AWS currently has a hard limit for the maximum number of rows that can be imported into SPICE for a single data set, which is 500 M rows. I currently don't see any option that could be used to visualize all of the data. Here are things that I already considered:

- **Splitting the full data set into individual QS datasets:** the problem with this approach is that QuickSight requires that each visual has a single dataset as an input, so values from multiple datasets cannot be shown in the same visual. I'm aware that multiple datasets can be used within one dashboard but that would not suit the use-case of having a single plot visualizing the data.
- **Pivoting the table:** the input table has a lot of rows, so changing the format from long to wide table would circumvent the SPICE row limitations. However, QuickSight doesn't seem to support using an array of columns a y-values to be plotted.
- **Creating a dataset per visualization:** Certain visualizations can theoretically be defined using fewer values than in the original data set. For example, to create a box plot over a set of groups, we mainly need the quartile values for each of the groups to be plotted, rather than the full data set, which would allow us to be below the SPICE limitation. However, QuickSight doesn't allow creating *custom* plots such as creation of a box plot where quartiles are already pre-processed.

Currently, the only viable approach I see is to create a dashboard per user, since most users would only be interested in a subset of rows from the full data set.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the approach taken, unfortunately, this limitation forces us to do some compromises.

Depending on the number of users, creating a dataset per user might become a headache to manage. So, I would suggest that if possible you use datasets that capture groups of users (example by user group, or user's country).

Pivoting the table might make it harder to build some visuals. As you said, if you pivot multiple values from different rows into an array field, then you would not be able to extract these easily in analyses (you could use string functions and to to extract them that way but there are limitations around this approach too).

Also creating a dataset per visualisation has maintenance overhead in that you would need to update and re-ingest the dataset most times when changing visualisations.

Some other approaches you might consider:

- **Aggregate multiple rows together** Example if your dataset has multiple rows for each user within the same minute, you could aggregate all these into 1 row and summing up values within that minute. The aggregation period should be as large as possible but keep in mind that this will affect the time granularity in your analyses/dashboards
- **Prune old data** If you are more interested in recent data, then you could add a filter to only keep say 1 month of activity. You could then have other non-SPICE (Direct Query) datasets that do not have this restriction but reports would be slower on older data.
- **Cache in an external database** You could load your data into some data warehousing database (such as AWS Redshift) and then not use SPICE in QuickSight. Of course, this will probably get more expensive.